# Como implementar mappers no R?

Tags: r, programação-funcional

Gostaria que a resposta contenha informações sobre:

- O que são mappers?
- Como criar um mapper no `R`?
- Em que situações mappers são usados (seu papel na programação funcional)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um **mapper** é uma função que relaciona elementos de um conjunto com elementos de do mesmo ou de outro conjunto. Isso é um conceito matemático.

Para entender melhor o que é um **mapper** no contexto de programação precisamos primeiro entender o que é um funcional.

Um funcional é uma função que recebe pelo menos uma função como argumento e retorna um vetor/lista. Existe uma categoria muito importante que funcionais que são os **maps**.

Essencialmente, um **map** é um loop escondido. Eles recebem um vetor e uma função e aplicam essa função para cada elemento do vetor recebido. Uma implementação simples em R poderia ser a seguinte:

```
meu_map <- function(x, f) {
  out <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    out[[i]] <- f(x[[i]])
  }
  out
}

meu_map(1:10, function(x) x^2)
```

**mapper** em programação é o nome que damos para a função que passamos como argumento para os funcionais da classe `map`.

Ao contrário do que muitos pensam, usar `maps` em R não está relacionado à performance e sim a legibilidade do código. É mais ou menos a mesma idéia de usar `for` ao invés de usar `while`. Também vale notar que em R, só usamos `maps` quando não existe uma opção vetorizada para fazer a mesma coisa - no exemplo acima o mais certo seria escrever simplesmente `x^2`.

No R base, criamos `mappers` da mesma forma que criamos funções, ainda que possamos usá-los como funções anônimas. No caso do `lapply` que é o funcional mais famoso do R, os mappers são o segundo argumento nas chamadas abaixo.

```
lapply(mtcars, mean)
lapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(x)/length(x))
```

O pacote `purrr` implementa uma forma um pouco diferente de escrever funções anônimas se você for usá-las como mappers.

```
library(purrr)
map(mtcars, ~sum(.x)/length(.x))
```

Essa nova notação faz com que escrever funções anônimas seja muito menos verboso, deixando o código mais simples. Neste caso, escrever `~sum(.x)/length(.x)` é equivalente a escrever: `function(.x) sum(.x)/length(.x)`. **Note** que ele sempre assume que o argumento da função tem o nome `.x`.